# Windows move command not moving the matching file to destination folder using bat

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file

I created a windows bat file which will create a directory and then create subdirectories finally it need to move the matching file to the destination folder but it is not moving showing error "A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found" but I have the matching string in the folder. Please help on this

my batch script shows below

```
set AUTOMATEDDIR=C:/test/2122/Inter/Test/WEB

CD %AUTOMATEDDIR%\..\Reports\Deliverable
FOR %%d IN (AgentCreate) DO (
    MKDIR "%%d"
    FOR %%e IN (Requests Responses) DO (
    echo inside
        MKDIR "%%d\%%e"
        MOVE "Unidentified\%%e\*%%d*" "%%d\%%e"
    )
)
```

when I execute the above script it shows below error

```
C:\test\2122\Inter\Test\Reports\Deliverable>(
MKDIR "AgentCreate"
 FOR %e IN (Requests Responses) DO (
echo inside
 MKDIR "AgentCreate\%e"
 MOVE "Unidentified\%e\*AgentCreate*" "AgentCreate\%e"
)
)

C:\test\2122\Inter\Test\Reports\Deliverable>(
echo inside
 MKDIR "AgentCreate\Requests"
 MOVE "Unidentified\Requests\*AgentCreate*" "AgentCreate\Requests"
)
inside
A duplicate file name exists, or the file
cannot be found.

C:\test\2122\Inter\Test\Reports\Deliverable>(
echo inside
 MKDIR "AgentCreate\Responses"
 MOVE "Unidentified\Responses\*AgentCreate*" "AgentCreate\Responses"
)
inside
A duplicate file name exists, or the file
cannot be found.
```

My folder Requests contains folder "Res_20121203_Test_1" as below

```
 C:\test\2122\Inter\Test\Reports\Deliverable\Unidentified\Requests\Res_20121203_Test_1

Res_20121203_Test_1 folder contains files like below

-20121203B001601-292XtOHAAgentCreate601
-20121203B002603-292XtOHAAgentCreate603
```

The above files matching "AgentCreate" need to move "AgentCreate\Requests" folder also matching files to "AgentCreate\Responses"

Please help on this why it is not moving.

Comment: Look on output commands. __MOVE__ should copy from directory `Unidentified\Requests` and `Unidentified\Responses` files matching pattern `*AgentCreate*`. But the files to move are in directory `Unidentified\Requests\Res_20121203_Test_1`, a subdirectory of `Unidentified\Requests`. Command __MOVE__ does not search in subdirectories and it is not possible to use a wildcard for a directory. Therefore the error message is correct: no file matching the pattern can be found by __MOVE__ in specified directory.

Answer (score 1):

```
FOR %%d IN (AgentCreate) DO (
    MKDIR "%%d" 2>nul
    FOR %%e IN (Requests Responses) DO (
    echo inside
        MKDIR "%%d\%%e" 2>nul
        FOR /f "delims=" %%t IN ('dir /s /b /a-d "Unidentified\%%e\*%%d*" 2^>nul') do MOVE "%%t" "%%d\%%e" >nul
    )
)
```

I misread the requirement. This worked for me.

The `2>nul` suppresses error messages. `>nul` suppresses "moved" reports and `2^>nul` suppresses 'file not found' output of the `dir`. The caret is necessary to tell `cmd` that the redirection is part of the command to be executed, not part of the `for`.

Essetially, scan the trget directory for matching files `/s` in subdirectories `/b` in basic form (filename only) `/a-d` and no directorynames.

You may want to try `echo move` to verify operation.

Please note that <kbd>\</kbd> is a directory-separator and <kbd>/</kbd> is a switch in winbatch. Some commands accept <kbd>/</kbd> as directory separators, but not all.

Comment: Hi Now the issue is files moved perfect to AgentCreate from the unidentified\Requests\Res_20121203_Test_1 folders but now the files are deleted in the unidentified\Requests\Res_20121203_Test_1  and Responses folder. I need to retain the files in both unidentified\Requests\Res_.20121203_Test_1 and Responses after moved.Please help on this

Comment: If you want a `copy` of the files, then change the `move` to a `copy`.